# How to make a Post request multiple times asynchronously in a Twilio function

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-functions

I am trying to achieve a functionality to send users(who are waiting in the queue after chat is initiated with a customer care) what number are they in the queue. I am calling an endpoint which gives me a number in the queue of the particular task.

For example, my queue number starts with 10 and gradually reduce to 0.

Furthermore, I want to create a loop/async function that makes the Post(I will change it to get once the functionality is working) request until the queue number is 0.

The functionality I am trying to achieve is in a Twilio function. Below is the code I am working on, right now it only makes the post request ones, but I want to keep updating users about their queue until an agent answers them.

```
exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {

var parameters = {"queueSid" : event.queueSid, "taskSid" : event.taskSid};

const apiPath = 'https://myEndPoint';
const response = await axios.post(apiPath, parameters );
console.log('Response', response.data)

callback(null,response)

};
```

Comment: When and how is this function called? Can't you just invoke multiple calls with `setInterval()`?

Comment: The above function I wrote is only called once via a Twilio StudioFlow. The setup is in a way when this function is called, the StudioFlow will passes the task to Flex so the instance is no longer available on the Twilio side so I thought the best way would be calling the api multiple times once the function is called from StudioFlow.